# Html column borders

Tags: html, css, html-table

How do I achieve the following look and feel using html and/or css?

[image]

I want to draw a border around column1.
Can this be done in a single table with a div or will I have to create a new table with a single td and multiple rows?

Comment: show what you tried so far

Comment: @p0enkie Try not to use `table` for layouts.

Comment: Downvoted for lack of attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you need:

**CSS:**

```css
 .border1
    {
      border: 2px solid black;
      border-bottom:0px;
    }
    .border2
    {
      border: 2px solid black;
      border-bottom:0px;
      border-top:0px;
    }
    .border3
    {
      border: 2px solid black;
      border-top:0px;
    }
    table
    {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>q</td>
      <td class="border1">q</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>q</td>
      <td class="border2">q</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>q</td>
      <td class="border2">q</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>q</td>
      <td class="border3">q</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Note: There are other ways to do this but since you wanted to use a table here you go(no need for two tables!!).

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it without table:**(to set items one each other use `flex`)

```css
.wrap{
display:flex;
}
.wrap-container{
border:1px solid black;
text-align:center;
width:30%;
margin-right:5px;
}
.elem{
border:1px solid black;
margin:5px;
margin-left: 5.5%;
width:150px;
padding:5px;
}
.title{

}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="wrap-container">
    <div class="title">Column1</div>
    <div class="elem">value</div>
    <div class="elem">value</div>
    <div class="elem">value</div>
    <div class="elem">value</div>
    <div class="elem">value</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="wrap-container">
    <div class="title">Column1</div>
    <div class="elem">value</div>
    <div class="elem">value</div>
    <div class="elem">value</div>
    <div class="elem">value</div>
    <div class="elem">value</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7283yugo/18/) for you.

```css
.option-wrapper {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.option-title {
  color: blue;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.options {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.option {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 6px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="option-wrapper">
  <div class="option-title">
    column1
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    <div class="option">
      option 1
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      option 1
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      option 1
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      option 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've created a table-less solution, hopefully, this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can write code like this.

CSS:

```
<style>
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}

.wrapper>div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.wrapper>div:last-child {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>view1</div>
    <div>view2</div>
    <div>view3</div>
    <div>view4</div>
    <div>view5</div>
</div>
```